# Can I re-wind gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, simulations, computational-physics

Suppose I perform an arbitrary simulation where I integrate the motions of a collection of particles which interact only gravitationally. Suppose I use a time reversible integrator (to be specific, let's say [leapfrog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration), which is also [symplectic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator), in case that's important). The fact that the integrator is termed 'time reversible' is highly suggestive that I should be able to run my simulation 'in reverse' simply by choosing time steps that are the negatives of the time steps used to run the simulation 'forwards'. But is this actually true? Does it matter how I calculate forces (accelerations)? For instance, does it matter if I'm using direct summation of $GM/r^2$, or a tree algorithm such as a [Barnes-Hut tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation)? One last simplification, let's suppose I have a computer capable of arbitrary floating point precision so that we can ignore roundoff error.

Comment: You could also use the *Fast Multipole Method* for $1/r^2$ forces like the electric force and gravity.

Comment: I think the situation that @lemon correctly describes is a lot worse than that. Almost every gravity problem with more than two masses is non-integrable, so running your simulation, forward or backward, will always lead to 100% errors. This is independent of the used numerical precision or the structure of the integrators. Given the reality of this, I think the proper solution would be to have controls that actually try to estimate the local Lyapunov exponents, which can be quite tame for most situations but will explode for strong interactions when particles come close.

Comment: @CuriousOne would a softened force law get around this somewhat? That way, there are no strong interactions, i.e. a = GM/(r^2+eps^2) where eps is some reasonably small softening length.

Comment: It would still be non-integrable, but the strong dependence on initial conditions may be softened quite a bit. What are you trying to simulate, if I may ask? Astrophysical objects like star clusters or galactic evolution?

Comment: @CuriousOne it's a theoretical question, as evidenced by the multitude of "impossible" assumptions ;) Most of the simulations I work with are cosmological/galaxy evolution sims.

Comment: Cool stuff! Intuitively I would almost say that the problem, on the scale of its long term evolution, almost screams to be non-time-reversal invariant. What do I mean by that? The scenario where rare close encounters kick stars out of the  the cluster/galaxy. Reversing the simulation will now require to treat the rogue object as a very specific initial condition of the reverse simulation, otherwise it won't get captured in the backwards run but simply fly trough.

Comment: @CuriousOne I don't think that's true.  For any N-Body system, there will be some precision which will lead to any arbitrary accuracy at any finite time in the future.  Additionally, because particle separations will always be non-zero (at *some* precision), the problem is integrable (at least in a practical sense).  As a "Theoretical" concept, there should be no problem with time-irreversibility with the appropriate deterministic algorithms, and "arbitrary" floating point precision.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix: Integrability has nothing to do with numerical precision. It's nature telling us to actually look more closely at the map between $t=0$ and $t\to \infty$. In the gravitational n-body problem in particular, bodies do not stay bound. That is a fundamentally different physical situation from playing a movie in reverse. In terms of computational complexity, by the way, just recording the forward data and reversing its order is far superior to trying to revert the integration, but then, there is nothing physical in that.

Comment: @CuriousOne yeah, that's obviously why I specific non-zero separations, making it integrable.... and obviously why I specified 'finite' so many times...

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix: Non-zero separations doesn't make it integrable, neither does finite. What you want is for the system to be "nice enough" which it can be, even though that makes it awfully boring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes. Although in reality you don't have unlimited floating point precision, and this will almost always break time-reversibility.

I should point out that not all integrators are time-reversible. For example, predictor-corrector schemes, and most schemes that deal with constraints. The Verlet method, however, *is* time-reversible, even for large time-steps. It is fairly trivial (but cumbersome) to show this by applying a forward integration step and then a backward one and getting back to where you started.

Related: [What does the time-reversibility of Verlet (or other) integration mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448005/what-does-the-time-reversibility-of-verlet-or-other-integration-mean)

In reality, however, limited floating-point precision will introduce small errors that will grow exponentially (due to the [Lyapunov instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability)) and break the time-reversibility.

Regarding force field optimisations, they will only break time-reversibility if the computed forces depend on the history of the trajectory or are in any way stochastic. This is not the case for a naive implementation of Barnes-Hut.